# Eclipse not recognizing a jar's source code files

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, src

So I've added a jar into my library, and when going in debug mode I can't navigate through the code because it gives me the error that Eclipse doesn't have the jar source code attached for that .class file. (I've always worked from IntelliJ and the jar file comes from IntelliJ too)
So the first thing I did is choose the same lib jar file which also contained the source code but Eclipse couldn't care less about it.
I've then tried to zip the src folder and then selecting that but no luck with that either, I've also tried to select the src folder unzipped but agian that didn't help

this is how the jar looks like when unarchived:

[image]

[image]

So as you can see the structure of the jar is the same as the project one, but it still can't find for example MenuModel.java

What is an actual way that I can do this?

---

**My Eclipse Info**

IBM Rational® Application Developer™ for WebSphere® Software

Version: 7.5.5.1

Build ID: 20100324_0059

---

PS: It's actually RAD but the base IDE is still Eclipse

Comment: Can you add your eclipse's details?

Comment: It's Rad but it's still based on the Eclpise IDE

Comment: And what jar are you trying to add?

Comment: It's a library of mine

Comment: @SandeepKumar I've added some pictures of my jar to simplify the understanding of the question